# AVPlayer not play the next song when screen goes lock

Tags: ios, avplayer

Im using `AVPlayer` to play song from `URLs`. I need to play songs continously when user play one song (all songs in the list one after the other) even when the screen doing to lock. But my problem is, when I play a song, after screen is lock current song is playing but the next song is not plays. This is my code.

Appdelegate.m

`

```
 // Registers this class as the delegate of the audio session.

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
// Allow the app sound to continue to play when the screen is locked.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);`
```

also set the info-plist `Required background modes` to `App plays audio`
If screen is not lock it plays allsongs one after the other. Only screen lock it plays the currently playing song only. How can I correct this issue.

Please help me,
Thanks

Comment: did you solve the problem? I'm in the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Same Problem over here ? Any ideas to solve this ?